# Gingerbread build with Android Studio - screen not responding to touch events

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have just migrated my project to Android Studio from Eclipse.
Now all builds for Gingerbread OS (tested on Nexus ONE & Nexus S devices) will run fine but the screen
will not respond to any events (One Nexus ONE the hardware roller actually works)
I assume it has something to do with the Gradle build but have no clue on what is actually happening.

Using 0.12.2 Gradle build.

compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

Anyone experiencing such issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was the problem.
Seems that if you will use the AppCompat v7 as a library project it will cause the Action Bar on Gingerbread builds to take up the whole screen space. I didn't notice it cause the action bar style was translucent.
Any ways, compiling the library as instructed by Google did the trick

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```